# PHP - Why there is a difference in the output of the echo statement and the print_r() function when viewed in a browser? Please explain

Tags: php, cookies, foreach

```
<?php
$cookies_data = array(

    'user_1' => array(
        '$user_name' => 'xyz khan', 
        '$user_email' => 'xyz@yahoo.se'
    ),

    'user_2' => array(
        '$user_name' => 'abc khan',
        '$user_email' => 'abc@gmail.com'
    ),

    'user_3' => array(
        '$user_name' => 'rst khan',
        '$user_email' => 'rst@lovemail.com'
    )
);

foreach ($cookies_data as $key1 => $value1) {
    $temp_key1 = $key1;
    foreach ($cookies_data[$temp_key1] as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo "<BR>$key2------------------$value2<BR>";//This line is for debugging 
        setcookie($key2, $value2, (time()+30), "/");//expire cookies after 30 seconds.
    }
}

    //Checking for debugging purpose if the cookies have been set.
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_COOKIE, TRUE), '</pre>';
?>
```

The echo statement ensure that the values in the $key2 and $value2 are correct and they are supplied as arguments in the next line to setcookies() method but the output is different in the browser. In the browser, we only get the last user_naem and user_email set but the other values are not shown by the print_r() method.

Comment: `setcookie()` does not populate the `$_COOKIE` array with new values. Those appear first with the next HTTP request.

Comment: Even when I refresh the page, the problem that I stated above persists. I tend to agree more with Boann below as I also think that one can have one key and one corresponding value for that key at the end of the loop but I want opinions from others as I am new in web programming and the cookies stuff as well as in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Each `user_name` or `user_email` cookie replaces the previous cookie of that name, because it's the same cookie name. At the end of the loop, only the most recently set value will be preserved.